# Find which WiFi hotspots are public or secured using programmatically

Tags: android, wifimanager

I want to know how I can filter hotspots that are secured or public using Android WiFi API or Android SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you need is in the android.net.wifi package. In particular, the ScanResult.capabilities string will contain either 'WPA2', 'WPA' or 'WEP' if the hotspot is secured.